# UIWebView is working but it doesn't show anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I'm using `UIWebView` in my app for lots of things and I've got this bug that I don't know how to solve.  The `UIWebView` didn't show anything at all. I logged all the `UIWebView` delegates and from what I could tell, it is working just fine. It showed the correct sequence of logged strings from `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`, `webViewDidStartLoad:`, and `webViewDidFinishLoad:`. And then I added this logging code to see the innerHTML of the web view:

```
NSString* html = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad: inner HTML string = %@\n", html);
```

The inner HTML is actually non null so it should've displayed something. Oh and FYI, this behaviour only appears on iPads, but it works fine on iPhones / iPods.

Can you guys please help me? I'm so lost right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you provide more code. Such as how you create your `UIWebView` for the iPad.

Comment: Ok, I've made it in the Storyboard as a subview of a view controller named WebViewController. And then it is set into an IBOutlet property named webView. And there's an NSString property named urlString for storing the url that will be called. The view controller will be pushed from another scene and the urlString will be defined in the `prepareForSegue`. The url will be called in the `viewWillAppear` method. That's about it.

Comment: Can you please share any code that you have around this to help us better understand your problem?

Comment: Here's the code of the view controller: http://tny.cz/fbbc986a

Comment: Please share your code in the question. Some of us can't access some links where we are due to them getting blocked by company firewalls.

Comment: Ok, after a few days debugging and looking at the project again, I've fixed it. And it has been entirely my fault from the start. Stupid me. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a few days debugging and looking at the project again, I've fixed it. And it has been entirely my fault from the start. Stupid me. :P

It turns out that I've been making the layout from Compact-w Compact-h size class in the Story board. And when I looked at it from the iPad size class (Regular-w Regular-h), it is disabled. I'm so embarrassed right now that such a stupid thing escaped my notice. Anyway, it's all good now. Thanks.

Comment: We all make mistakes it doesn't make us stupid and it shouldn't be embarrassing especially if you are just starting out so don't worry about it to much